# Requesting Manifest.permission.USE_SIP acts weird

Tags: android

I'm requesting the `Manifest.permission.USE_SIP` permission. The strange thing is that even though it seems to be considered a dangerous permission, when I request it it seems to be already given so no popup appears and neither does it appear as a switch under Settings->Permission.

And another strange thing is that it seems there's another additional permission: [image]

which is the CONFIGURE_SIP [image]

which I am indeed specifying in the manifest that I need but that one's not a dangerous permission, so why is it in the list under Settings?

Comment: Is that behavior on one specific device?

Comment: Tried it on two genymotion simulators on OS 6.0.0

Comment: What about real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out (at least the first part, the important part). I was requesting multiple permissions at a time and before requesting the `USE_SIP` one I was requesting and granting the `REA_PHONE_STATE` permission. They both are part of the large group of permissions `PHONE`. Apparently, and this is what I did not know, is that once a permission group item receives the OK from the user, then all of its items are fine.

Now ... I still can't figure out why the `CONFIGURE_SIP` permission is visible under Settings, but I've noticed that on 7.0.0 it's not being displayed ... so in case anyone wants to open a question on that, be my guest.